# C# != operator won't work properly

Tags: c#, operators

When this runs:

```
if (Title != "") {
     Server.s.Log("title found: " + Title);
     if (TitleColor != "") {
         NameTitle = "[" + TitleColor + Title + NameColor + "]";
     } else {
         NameTitle = "[" + Title + "]";
     }
 } else {
     NameTitle = "";
 }
```

It thinks that the title has a value, when in fact, the title is most definitely just "", help me please?

Comment: Can you debug your code and check what is the value of Title?

Comment: Try using String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title)

Comment: is title a string? i bet it's something like a label

Comment: @AnthonyBlake The question says "When this runs", so I assume it compiles. So it can't be a label

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may be confusing an empty string with a null value. Try this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
```

or this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Title))
```

depending on your needs.

Comment: Should these methods always be used instead of manual checking for an empty string?

Comment: They are semantically different from just checking for an empty string, just as a Null value is semantically different from an empty string. If in doubt, they should probably be used, but consider what is appropriate in each case. if you know the string is not Null, then `!= ""` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is an empty string and not null?  Those are different.  If it could be either, you can use [String.IsNullOrEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I believe Title is string.

Try..

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:  [String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)